# Button and ToggleButton in wpf Toolbar using MVVM

Tags: wpf, button, datatemplate, toolbar, togglebutton

I have a wpf Toolbar in a ToolbarTray inside my application which must host Buttons and ToggleButtons.
Can someone suggest me how to implement this behavior in MVVM?
The code below is what I have right now:

```
 <ToolBarTray Margin="5,30,5,30" MinWidth="35" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent">
            <ToolBar x:Name="ToolBarControl" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ToolBarItems}" >
                <ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,15"
                        Template="{Binding ToolBarIcon}" 
                        cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Select()]"
                        IsEnabled="True"
                        ToolTip="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
```

Where the Button could be a normal Button or a ToggleButton.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM pattern, your model class will contain the properties (all data objects) which you want to bind and display in view. So ToolBarItems collection will be part of model.

Your view basically will contain the above code you have written. And in code behind file, there will be an object of type model class as a property.

Your viewmodel can initialize the model and view objects and bind the model to view's datacontext.